# Error while running Test Cases in SoapUI from eclipse

Tags: soapui, eclipse

I am getting the below error while invoking my test suite:

```
12:01:56,498 ERROR [SoapUI] An error occurred [com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoDiscoveryMethodFactory], see error log for details
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoDiscoveryMethodFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadAutoFactories(LoaderBase.java:112)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadFactories(LoaderBase.java:80)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPluginFactories(PluginLoader.java:141)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:104)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:54)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.doInstallPlugin(PluginManager.java:141)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.access$600(PluginManager.java:43)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.computeSequentially(PluginManager.java:420)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:377)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:382)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:365)
    at java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask.exec(RecursiveTask.java:93)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.execTask(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:604)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:784)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.work(ForkJoinPool.java:646)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:398)
```

Although the tests run fine. But these errors do come before invoking the test suite. What could be the possible reason?

Comment: These plugins are only required for SOAPUI Pro, disable the plugins by renaming the ~\.soapuios\plugins folder to something link ~\.soapuios\plugins.disabled.

Answer (score -1):

This class is missing:
`com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoDiscoveryMethodFactory`

Make sure eclipse can locate all the class libraries before running.  The references need to be included in the compiler for it to find them...these could be PATH variables in the OS or specific import statements after library references are included into the project.

Answer (score -1):

Hey it seems we got a ClassNotFoundException. Below are the ways to deal with it which could be of help.

1. Verify that the name of the requested class is correct and that the appropriate .jar file exists in your classpath. If not, you must explicitly add it to your application’s classpath.
2. In case the specified .jar file exists in your classpath then, your application’s classpath is getting overriden and you must find the exact classpath used by your application.
3. In case the exception is caused by a third party class, you must identify the class that throws the exception and then, add the missing .jar files in your classpath.

Source: [Java Code Geeks](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-how-to-solve-class-not-found-exception/)